# Tikzcd "Crossing Over" Background Color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm making a Tikzcd diagram but I wanted to add color to the background of my document like so:

[image]

However, there's clearly an issue with the middle diagram.

In the middle diagram, I wanted to make cube diagram, and as to implement the 3D-effect I had to use the `crossing over` attribute for those arrows. However, this has now made me realize that Tikzcd implements this by assuming your background color is white; they just put a white rectangle around it. This explains why, when a user wants to cross over two arrows, one must write `crossing over` on the arrow which is crossing over the other.

It seems unlikely that it's impossible to change the background color from white to something else. Does anyone know how? In addition, it also seems like it might be useful to know how to adjust the thickness of this white rectangle, which would be a nice bonus if anyone knows how to do that too.

By the way, I'm using `pagecolor` for the background color, if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the `background color` in the options for the `tikzcd` environment. This color will then be used for `crossing over`. As you did not provide a minimal working example, I use the example from the documentation of the `tikz-cd` package:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\pagecolor{yellow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=scriptsize, column sep=scriptsize, background color=yellow]
    & f^* E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] & & E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[dd] \\
    f^* E \arrow[rr, crossing over] \arrow[dd] & & E \\
    & U \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] & & V \arrow[dl] \\
    M \arrow[rr] & & N \arrow[from=uu, crossing over]\\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you!