# Change tikz-cd arrow 'background color' in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, tikz-cd

I'm typesetting a diagram in `beamer`. It renders like this:

[image]

**EDIT**: the problem appears to be just the background color of the arrow. It's white and not transparent, therefore stands out on the black background.

This is the result I want:

[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}

\definecolor{colornormaltext}{HTML}{e5e8f8}
\definecolor{colorbg}{HTML}{101316}
\definecolor{colorgold}{HTML}{db9a46}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=colorbg}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=colornormaltext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{equation*}
            \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
                Sh_ W \&[-3ex] \&[-3ex] Sh_ V\\
                \& Msbl
                \arrow[""{name=0, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, "{f_*}"', shift right=2, from=1-1, to=1-3]
                \arrow[""{name=1, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, "{f^*}"', shift right=2, from=1-3, to=1-1]
                \arrow["{O_W}", from=2-2, to=1-1]
                \arrow[""{name=2, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, "{O_V}"', from=2-2, to=1-3]
                \arrow["\dashv"{anchor=center, rotate=-90}, draw=none, from=1, to=0]
                \arrow[shift left=2, Rightarrow, "\hat f", from=2, to=1-1]
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The incriminated arrow is the very last one in the code:

```
\arrow[shift left=2, Rightarrow, "\hat f", from=2, to=1-1]
```

Comment: As always on the site, you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full, but mminimal, self contained example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add a lot of stuff (what might not match your situation) in order to even test.

Comment: A normal `\Rightarrow` pointing where?

Comment: @egreg in the same direction. It's just rendered without that solid white.

Comment: @daleif right, I'm sorry. I'll edit my question later with a mwe

Comment: Any news? You receive two answers. Does any of them solve your problem? If does, please accept it, if not please inform us by comment, what is missed in received answers that their authors can correct them. Your question is no entirely clear.

Comment: @Zarko done! Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in a different [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529903/tikzcd-crossing-over-background-color).

The tikz-cd environment has a setting for the background color, which you would need to set to black in your case, i.e. simply change

```
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
```

to

```
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, background color=black]
```

and it gives the desired result.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Besides setting the `background color` to `colorbg` which is also necessary for other things (crossing over and description nodes), the [great `nfold` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642548/16595) can be used that doesn't draw a thick line with the background color.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, decorations.pathmorphing, nfold}
\definecolor{colornormaltext}{HTML}{e5e8f8}
\definecolor{colorbg}{HTML}{101316}
\definecolor{colorgold}{HTML}{db9a46}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=colorbg}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=colornormaltext}
\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={/tikz/double/.append style=/tikz/nfold},% every cd should use nfold
  background color=colorbg
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small, ampersand replacement=\&]
Sh_W \&      \& Sh_V\\
     \& Msbl
\arrow["f_*"', shift right=2, from=1-1, to=1-3]
\arrow[from=1-1, to=1-3, draw=none, "\dashv" {rotate=-90, auto=false}]
\arrow["f^*"', shift right=2, from=1-3, to=1-1]
\arrow["{O_W}"  name=OW, from=2-2, to=1-1]
\arrow["{O_V}"' name=OV, from=2-2, to=1-3]
\arrow[Rightarrow, "\hat f" near start, from=OV, to=1-1, bend left=10]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You should provide complete MWE, not just fragment diagram code.
- Your code fragment is a bit strange, so it is hart to understand what is your problem.
- I just clean-up your code and try to reproduce showed image (without thick arrows which purpose is not clear)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{tikz-cd diagram}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[
    row sep = large,
arrow style = tikz,
          > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}  
                    ]
Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_{\infty} \ar[rr,shift right=0.5em, "1_t*" ', "\bot"]
    &   & Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_t  \ar[ll,shift right=0.5em,"1^*_t" ']    \\
    & \mathsf{Msbl} \ar[ul, "\mathcal{O}_{\infty}"]
                    \ar[ur, "\mathcal{O}_t" ']
        &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

It is still (unfortunately) not clear where arrow in the middle of diagram should be. Also if it need to be `Rightarrow` In case that it need to cross arrows from node `2-2` to `1-3` result can be ugly (to my opinion). So below are two examples of:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{tikz-cd diagram}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[
    row sep = large,
arrow style = tikz,
          > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
                    ]
Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_{\infty} \ar[rr,shift right=0.5em, "1_t*" ', "\bot"]
    &   & Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_t  \ar[ll,shift right=0.5em,"1^*_t" ']    \\
    & \mathsf{Msbl} \ar[ul, "\mathcal{O}_{\infty}"]
                    \ar[ur, ""{name=Ot,right}]
                    \ar[ur, "\mathcal{O}_t" ']
                    \ar[dashrightarrow, from=Ot, to=1-1,yshift=-1ex]
        &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or (only diagram code):

```
Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_{\infty} \ar[rr,shift right=0.5em, "1_t*" ', "\bot"]
    &   & Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_t  \ar[ll,shift right=0.5em,"1^*_t" ']    \\
    & \mathsf{Msbl} \ar[ul, "\mathcal{O}_{\infty}"]
                    \ar[ur, draw=none, ""{name=Ot,right}]
                    \ar[ur, "\mathcal{O}_t" ']
                    \ar[Rightarrow, crossing over, from=Ot, to=1-1,yshift=-1ex]
        &
```

[image]

or with `Rightarrow` inside diagram:

```
Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_{\infty} \ar[rr,shift right=0.5em, "1_t*" ', "\bot"]
    &   & Sh_{\mathrm{a.e.}}W_t  \ar[ll,shift right=0.5em,"1^*_t" ']    \\
    & \mathsf{Msbl} \ar[ul, "\mathcal{O}_{\infty}"]
                    \ar[ur, "\mathcal{O}_t" ', ""{name=Ot}]
                    \ar[Rightarrow,  from=Ot, to=1-1,yshift=-1ex]
        &
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Zarko, thanks for your effort. I hope the question is now more clear: the arrow in the middle is needed.

Comment: @mattecapu, does it need to cross arrow from "Mslb" to "SHa.e.Wt"?

Comment: No, that's not the problem (or better: I now how to take care of that). The problem is in the color, as stated in the updated question. I don't understand why the arrow gets filled with white color, instead of being transparent.

Comment: @mattecapu, this arrow is actually compose composed from two arrows: first id black, over it is drawn for line width smaller white arrow.. So, what you like to have is not possible to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to create MWE but have you tried adding  `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` to your preamble?  Then, try this:

```
\arrow[""{name=0, anchor=center, inner sep=0,latex-}, "{f_*}"', shift right=2, from=1-1, to=1-3]
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't work!